# Thick text outline

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to add a thick outline to text. I found this trick

```
text-shadow:
    -1px -1px 0 #00f,
    1px -1px 0 #00f,
    -1px 1px 0 #00f,
    1px 1px 0 #00f;
```

But it only works for 1px outline. The outline is also not very smooth, on a big fonts it appears broken. Is there a way to make a thicker smooth outline of 2 or 3px? CSS or JS or jQuery plugins, anything would be helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT:** You have to use all of the permutations, including ones like `-1px 3px 0px #00f` or `3px -2px 0px #00f`.

```
text-shadow:
  -1px -1px 0 #00f,
  1px -1px 0 #00f,
  -1px 1px 0 #00f,
  1px 1px 0 #00f,

  -2px -2px 0 #00f,
  2px -2px 0 #00f,
  -2px 2px 0 #00f,
  2px 2px 0 #00f,

  -3px -3px 0 #00f,
  3px -3px 0 #00f,
  -3px 3px 0 #00f,
  3px 3px 0 #00f;
```

Comment: It doesnt really simulate a stroke, its broken on the sides and this will be very visible on large fonts....

Comment: @skyisred The text-shadow method has this effect even without multiple layers of `text-shadow`.

Comment: Yes:) Its not so visible tho. But thats one of the reasons I was looking for a better solution...

Comment: @skyisred You have to use every combination. `-1px 3px #00f`, `2px -1px 00f` etc.